# my js validation doesn't work as I would like (regex)

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation

Hi everyone i have question about my code the plan was that the script was supposed to display message if someone did not enter anything in input or enter somethink thats did not match to my pattern (but if someone lift message will disappear [this doesnt work]) and i dont know where is problem and how to fix it

here is my code:

html

```
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="odp.php" method="post" id="form">
        <div>
            <label for="imie">Imie</label>
            <input type="text" name="imie" id="imie" placeholder="Imie" required>
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="nazwisko">Nazwisko</label>
            <input type="text" name="nazwisko" id="nazwisko" placeholder="Nazwisko" required>
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="pesel">Pesel</label>
            <input type="number" placeholder="pesel" name="pesel" id="pesel" required>
            <span></span>
        </div><br>
        adres zamieszkania:
        <div>
            <label for="kod">kod</label>
            <input type="text" name="kod" id="kod" placeholder="kod" required>
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="miejscowosc">miejscowość</label>
            <input type="text" name="miejscowosc" id="miejscowosc" placeholder="Miejscowość" required>
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="ulica">ulica</label>
            <input type="text" name="ulica" id="ulica" placeholder="Ulica" required>
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="nrdomu">nr domu</label>
            <input type="text" name="nrdomu" id="nrdomu" placeholder="nr domu" required>
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="nrmieszkania">nr mieszkania</label>
            <input type="text" name="nrmieszkania" id="nrmieszkania" placeholder="nr mieszkania">
            <span></span>
        </div><br>

        <div>
            <label for="emial">Emial</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" id="email" required>
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="number">Numer Telefonu</label>
            <input type="number" name="nrtel" placeholder="Numer-telefonu" id="number" required>
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" id="submit">
    </form>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my js

````
let nazwisko = document.getElementById('nazwisko');
let pesel = document.getElementById('pesel');
let kod = document.getElementById('kod');
let miejscowosc = document.getElementById('miejscowosc');
let ulica = document.getElementById('ulica');
let nrdomu = document.getElementById('nrdomu');
let nrmieszkania = document.getElementById('nrmieszkania');
let email = document.getElementById('email');
let number = document.getElementById('number');
let span = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
let form = document.getElementById('form');

var arr = [imie,nazwisko,pesel,kod,miejscowosc,ulica,nrdomu,nrmieszkania,email,number];


    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i){
        
        var regex;
        console.log(arr[i]);
        if(i == 0 || i == 1 || i == 4 || i == 5){
            regex = /^[A-Za-zĄĘĆŁŃÓŚŻŹąęćłńóśżź]{3,100}$|^[A-Za-zĄĘĆŁŃÓŚŻŹąęćłńóśżź]+[A-Za-zĄĘĆŁŃÓŚŻŹąęćłńóśżź0-9\s\-]+[A-Za-zĄĘĆŁŃÓŚŻŹąęćłńóśżź0-9]{1,100}$/;
            console.log(arr[i].value.match(regex));
        }

        if(i == 2){
            regex = /^[0-9]{11}$/;
            console.log(regex);
        }

        if(i == 3){
            regex = /^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}$/i;
            console.log(regex);
        }

        if(i == 6){
            regex = /[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|1000/i;
            console.log(regex);
        }

        if(i == 7){
            regex = /[0-9]/gm;
            console.log(regex);
        }

        if(i == 8){
            regex  = /\b[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.\w{2,4}\b/gi;
            console.log(regex);
        }

        if(i == 9){
            regex = /^(?:\+\d\d)?\d{3}(-?)\d{3}\1\d(\d\d)?$/gm;
            console.log(regex);
        }

        arr[i].onblur = function(){
            if(arr[i].value.match(regex)){
                span[i].innerHTML = "";
            }else{
                span[i].innerHTML = "Uzupełnij " + arr[i].name;
                span[i].style.color = 'red';
            }

        }

        if(i == 7){
            arr[i].onblur = span[i].innerHTML = "";
        }
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

the `<span></span>` tags you are using in the Html do not have an id to which your logic can set the value that you define in the JS

```
else{
  span[i].innerHTML = "Uzupełnij " + arr[i].name;
  span[i].style.color = 'red';
}
```

Comment: yea thats dont have id becouse i use document.getElementsByTagName instead document.getElementById Then this piece of code works this script display message but if someone change value to "good value" thats match to my pattern message dont disapper `if(arr[i].value.match(regex)){
                span[i].innerHTML = "";`     this element doesnt work